# How to use sed to replace the first column (unknown floating point) of a given row, then pad with spaces to nth character

Tags: bash, replace, sed, padding

I have a file that I wish to edit with sed (or awk or similar) via a script.

Example file contents:

```
    362.4318             str1                 uag tj
-19.275620800            string2 (blah)       uag tt
367.                     randomtext           uag tu
 0.05699651698647584     blab*blah(something) uag tv
    .008306              la*la(word)          uag tw
  54                     la*la(word)          uag tx
```

I have an associative array that contains the row number to be edited, and another that contains the new value to be inserted.  I can mostly do the replacement with the following command (though this fails for row 6 in the example since there is no decimal):

```
 sed  -i ''${rowArray[$key]}'s/.*\.[0-9]*/'${valueArray[$key]}'/'  $file
```

Also, The unaltered part of the string (2nd column and beyond) should always start at the 26th character (or later if the new value requires more than 24 characters), even if it was originally to the left of the 26th character.  I've read a bit about padding, but I don't understand the syntax.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the value of `${rowArray[$key]}` and `${valueArray[$key]}`?

Comment: Not an answer, but this link may help you with the padding syntax - I found it very useful: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/

Comment: @konsolebox For example, the ${rowArray[$key]}=4 and ${valueArray[$key]} = 0.04793620056

Comment: @user3719139 Ok. How's my solution?

Comment: @ValdarMoridin Thanks for the link.  That's one of the references I've been trying to wrap my head around.  I'm recently self taught, so I never know if what I'm misunderstanding is fundamental or complex :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sed -i -r "${rowArray[$key]}s|^\s*-?[0-9.]+|${valueArray[$key]}|" file
```

Or

```
sed -i "${rowArray[$key]}s|^[[:blank:]]*-\?[0-9.]\+|${valueArray[$key]}|" file
```

- `0-9` can also be `[:digit:]`
- `[:blank:]` can also be just `<space>\t`.

#### Update

```
printf -v paddedValue '%24s ' "${valueArray[$key]}"
sed -i -r "${rowArray[$key]}s|^\s*-?[0-9.]+\s*|$paddedValue|" file
```

Comment: A quick analysis leads me to believe this works for replacing, but doesn't do any padding.

Comment: @user3719139 You can use `printf` to do the padding e.g. `printf -v paddedValue "%<expr>" "${valueArray[$key]}"` and use `$paddedValue` as the replacement form instead. I suggest formatting `$paddedValue` with included spaces after it so you can replace the column uniformly without affecting the alignment of the column that follows it and change `^\s*-?[0-9.]+` to `^\s*-?[0-9.]+\s*` so you could also replace the space after it.

Comment: I like it!  I'll give it a go.

Comment: Nailed the padding!  Great!

Comment: @user3719139 Ok. Please accept the answer if you see it as your solution thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
eval sed -i $'${rowArray[$key]}s/\S*/${valueArray[$key]}/'  $file
```

However some may say that eval is evil!

Comment: Haven't used eval yet.  I'll look into it.  Why evil? :)